# Is there any way to recognize combination ctrl+c via Marshal?

Tags: c#

I try to detect `ctrl+c` stroke in background process. I can detect any key which has a keycode like PrintScreen but I have problem with `ctrl+c` combination.

```
  private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                if (((Keys)vkCode).Equals(Keys.PrintScreen)) {
                  //HOW_TO_DETECT_CTRL+C
                }
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```

How to detect ctrl+c? Is there any way besides remembering last pressed key in a field?